# Struts2 File Upload

Tags: jsp, file-upload, struts2

I want to upload multiple files in one form and that number of files is varying from user to another, ex. a user may upload 2 files and another user could upload 12 files. I want to know how could I create a loop or something in the jsp struts2 form such that when a user uploads a file it adds its name to a list and he/she could upload another file and be added to the list and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this by using two struts2 plugin which are, Struts2 JQuery Plugin and Struts2 Scope Plugin

The answer is as following:

include those dependencies in your maven POM file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.struts2scopeplugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-scope-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

and we create a class to prepare the form as follows:

```
 public class PrepareUpload extends ActionSupport{
     @In (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
      @Out (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
      private List<File> fileUploadi = new ArrayList<File>();

      @In (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
      @Out (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
        private List<String> fileUploadContentTypei = new ArrayList<String>();

      @In (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
      @Out (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
        private List<String> fileUploadFileNamei = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Action(value = "/prepareupload", results = {
            @Result(location = "upload.jsp", name = "success")
          })
          @End
    public String execute() throws Exception

      {
        return SUCCESS;

      }

    public List<File> getFileUploadi() {
        return fileUploadi;
    }

    public void setFileUploadi(List<File> fileUploadi) {
        this.fileUploadi = fileUploadi;
    }

    public List<String> getFileUploadContentTypei() {
        return fileUploadContentTypei;
    }

    public void setFileUploadContentTypei(List<String> fileUploadContentTypei) {
        this.fileUploadContentTypei = fileUploadContentTypei;
    }

    public List<String> getFileUploadFileNamei() {
        return fileUploadFileNamei;
    }

    public void setFileUploadFileNamei(List<String> fileUploadFileNamei) {
        this.fileUploadFileNamei = fileUploadFileNamei;
    }

}
```

and a class for the add to list and to handle ajax call as follows:

```
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7968544374444173511L;
  private static final Log  log              = LogFactory.getLog(UploadAction.class);


  private String            echo;
  @In (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
  @Out (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
  private List<File> fileUploadi = new ArrayList<File>();
  private List<File> fileUpload = new ArrayList<File>();
  @In (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
  @Out (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
    private List<String> fileUploadContentTypei = new ArrayList<String>();
  private List<String> fileUploadContentType = new ArrayList<String>();
  @In (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
  @Out (scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
    private List<String> fileUploadFileNamei = new ArrayList<String>();
  private List<String> fileUploadFileName = new ArrayList<String>();
  @Action(value = "/uploada", results = {
    @Result(location = "simpleecho.jsp", name = "success")
  })
  @Begin
  public String execute() throws Exception
  {

fileUploadi.addAll( fileUpload);
fileUploadFileNamei.addAll(fileUploadFileName);
fileUploadContentTypei.addAll(fileUploadContentType);
   for (int i = 0;  i < fileUploadFileNamei.size();  i++)
   {
       if (echo == null)
           echo =   fileUploadFileNamei.get(i);
       else
      echo +=  "<br>" + fileUploadFileNamei.get(i);
    log.info(echo);
   }
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String getEcho()
  {
    return echo;
  }


  public List<File> getFileUpload() {
        return fileUpload;
    }

    public void setFileUpload(List<File> fileUpload) {
        this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
    }

    public List<String> getFileUploadContentType() {
        return fileUploadContentType;
    }

    public void setFileUploadContentType(List<String> fileUploadContentType) {
        this.fileUploadContentType = fileUploadContentType;
    }

    public List<String> getFileUploadFileName() {
        return fileUploadFileName;
    }

    public void setFileUploadFileName(List<String> fileUploadFileName) {
        this.fileUploadFileName = fileUploadFileName;
    }

    public List<File> getFileUploadi() {
        return fileUploadi;
    }

    public void setFileUploadi(List<File> fileUploadi) {
        this.fileUploadi = fileUploadi;
    }

    public List<String> getFileUploadContentTypei() {
        return fileUploadContentTypei;
    }

    public void setFileUploadContentTypei(List<String> fileUploadContentTypei) {
        this.fileUploadContentTypei = fileUploadContentTypei;
    }

    public List<String> getFileUploadFileNamei() {
        return fileUploadFileNamei;
    }

    public void setFileUploadFileNamei(List<String> fileUploadFileNamei) {
        this.fileUploadFileNamei = fileUploadFileNamei;
    }




    }
```

and finally the jsp should be something like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" defaultLoadingText="Please wait ..."/>
<s:head />
</head>

<body>
<h1>File Upload:</h1>

<s:form action="uploada" 
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="xhtml" >

<s:file label="File:" name="fileUpload" size="40" />

 <div id="result" >Add Files Below:</div>
<sj:submit 
            targets="result" 
            button="true" 
            validate="true" 
            value="Add File" 
            indicator="indicator"
            parentTheme="xhtml"
            />
<sj:submit 
            button="true" 
            validate="true" 
            value="Submit" 
            indicator="indicator"
            parentTheme="xhtml"
            />

</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I change it to upload multiple files at once? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393581/need-to-upload-multiple-files-at-once

Answer (score 3):

You can use build in Struts2 multiple file uploading feature.In your Jsp file you have to define something like

```
<s:form action="doMultipleUploadUsingList" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file label="File (1)" name="upload" />
    <s:file label="File (2)" name="upload" />
    <s:file label="FIle (3)" name="upload" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

which will send these files to Your action class and you have the option of Collecting the file content as a list

```
public class MultipleFileUploadUsingListAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<File> uploads = new ArrayList<File>();
    private List<String> uploadFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> uploadContentTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    // There getter and setter methods

}
```

here

```
[File Name] : File - the actual File
[File Name]ContentType : String - the content type of the file
[File Name]FileName : String - the actual name of the file uploaded (not the HTML name)
```

For detail refer to the multiple file upload page of Struts2

[Multiple File Upload](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-UploadingMultipleFilesusingLists)

Showing user an option to add more file on the JSP page is matter of how to want to display that.All you need to take care when you show him file-upload box name should be same so that `Struts2 param interceptor` can set them as a list in your Action class

Comment: I know how to use the action and this multiple file form. what i don't know is how to make the number of uploaded files up to 100 for example

Comment: can i do a loop for example when he uploads a file it adds it and asks him for another file to upload and when the user submits the form i could handle it with an array of files

Comment: yup that's only a UI iplimentation and has nothing to do with the action

Comment: i believe you are looking something like gmail provide,so all it provide is i frame enabled feature can find details here http://css.dzone.com/news/upload-files-like-gmail-client.You have to use some kind of client side script of what you are looking at

Comment: Can i use <s:iterator or javascript to acheive this ?

Comment: Well you will not able to use iterator in this case i believe you have to use some kind of JS or the one kind of i-frame thing

Comment: umesh, I did it by using the struts2 jquery plugin and scope plugin. i'll post the solution soon

Comment: yup..jquery plugin is also good but i will suggest you to go with jquery itself rather than wrapping it.

Comment: its easier to use the plugin:)

Comment: yes!! but that also means making yourself depedent upon that.Anyways that a personal choice and taste..in end we need to get work done :)