# Multiple file uploads in struts 2

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

I have a problem in uploading files using struts2. I have multiple file tags like

```xml
<s:file name="fileUpload_5534" multiple="multiple"/>

<s:file name="fileUpload_5585" multiple="multiple"/>

<s:file name="fileUpload_5595" multiple="multiple"/>
```

These file tags are created dynamically and again can have multiple files uploads as I have specified `multiple="multiple"`. Can anyone suggest the solution for this kind of uploads.

Comment: Please consider looking at your question after you post it; you would have noticed your JSP fragment was invisible. You should have a map of files using normal S2 collection field naming syntax.

Comment: Multiple File Upload Using Struts 2 :http://geekonjava.blogspot.com/2015/07/multiple-file-upload-using-struts-2.html

Comment: @GeekOnJava or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265 ;) BTW good article

Answer (score 1):

You can upload multiple files from a single `<s:file>` element [with `multiple="multiple"` like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265).

You can also upload multiple files from many `<s:file>` elements (that allow a single file for each one) in the same way, handling the names of the `<s:file>`s to point to a list on the Action.

Do you really want to upload a *`List`s of `Lists`* of `File`s ?

If yes, I suggest you to model an object, like `MyFileListObject`, containing the lists of data needed:

```java
class MyFileListObject {
    private List<File> files;
    private List<String> filesContentType;
    private List<String> filesFileName;    

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

and then expose a `List<MyFileListObject>` through the Action.

Alternatively, you can granulate it more, defining a new object, like `MyFileObject`,

```java
class MyFileObject {
    private File files;
    private String filesContentType;
    private String filesFileName;    

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

,listed in `MyFileListObject`:

```java
class MyFileListObject {
    private List<MyFileObject> files;

    /* getter and setter */
}
```

and then expose a `List<MyFileListObject>` through the Action.

But it seems overkill to me... which kind of page should let many `<input type="file"/>` upload many files each one in a single post ?