# in uploading file null pointer exception near filePath

Tags: java, struts2

Here am using struts2 to upload file I am getting null pointer exception near String filePath when I am going to upload my file,could anybbody plz help me out in this problem.....and i want to find extension of the what I have uploaded.

```
 public class ImportAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

        public File getUploadfile() {
            return uploadfile;
        }

        public String getUploadFileName() {
            return uploadFileName;
        }

        public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
            this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
        }

        public void setUploadfile(File uploadfile) {
            this.uploadfile = uploadfile;
        }
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private LoginBean bean;
        private File uploadfile;

        public String getFileContentType() {
            return fileContentType;
        }

        public void setFileContentType(String fileContentType) {
            this.fileContentType = fileContentType;
        }
        private String uploadFileName;
        private String fileContentType;
        private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
        RegisterDAO dao = new RegisterDAO();

        public LoginBean getBean() {
            return bean;
        }

        public void setBean(LoginBean bean) {
            this.bean = bean;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * @throws
         * Exception
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public String execute() throws Exception {
            try {
                String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
                File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.uploadFileName);
                FileUtils.copyFile(this.uploadfile, fileToCreate);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                addActionError(e.getMessage());
                return INPUT;
            }
            Model m = new Model();
            String result = m.fileimport(uploadfile, uploadFileName);
            if (result.equals(SUCCESS)) {
                return SUCCESS;
            } else {
                addActionError(getText(result));
                return "failure";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void validate() {
            System.out.println("inside validate of LA");
        }

        @Override
        public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
            this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are u getting hold of valid/non-null servletRequest object?

Comment: sorry am not getting this comment thanks

Comment: just check whether your servletRequest object is non-null. try to put a null if check for that.

Comment: Your telling about this right   private HttpServletRequest servletRequest; thanks......

Comment: have you  tried `servletRequest.getContextPath().getRealPath("/");` ??

Comment: String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); I am trying this one...

Comment: Try step by step debugging. Since `String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");` is throwing null pointer, that means either `servletRequest` or `servletRequest.getSession()` or `servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext()` or `servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` is null. It's likely that `servletRequest` is null. So, check each of those to know where the null pointer is coming from.

Comment: am not getting where it is coming....

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `servletRequest` is null and hence it is causing the null pointer exception. You may have to intialize it through context.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
private File   uploadfile;
private String uploadFileName;
private String fileContentType;
```

It should be changed (along with Setters) into:

```
private File   uploadFile; /* Uppercase F */
private String uploadFileName;
private String uploadContentType; /* "upload" prefix */
```

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265).

Comment: @Andrea you just missed, the name is `uploadfile` and hence the other params will be `uploadfileFileName` and `uploadfileContentType`

Comment: Because you didn't even [read the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload.html), or [a simple Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/). @coding_idiot: you are right, nice catch. I still prefer just upload, or fileUpload (camelCased), to avoid uglyness like `uploadfileFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

Field names are wrong. Change to

```
private File uploadfile;
private String uploadfileFileName;
private String uploadfileContentType;

//getters & setters
```