# I am getting nullpointer exception when in uploading files

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

Hi from this code I am getting null pointer exception ,When I am going to read uploadfilename I am trying lot to solve this problem but this problem is not resolving could anybody plz help me out in this ....

```
public class ImportAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private File uploadFile;
    private String uploadfileFileName;
    private String uploadfileContentType;
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public String getUploadfileFileName() {
        return uploadfileFileName;
    }

    public void setUploadfileFileName(String uploadfileFileName) {
        this.uploadfileFileName = uploadfileFileName;
    }

    public String getUploadfileContentType() {
        return uploadfileContentType;
    }

    public void setUploadfileContentType(String uploadfileContentType) {
        this.uploadfileContentType = uploadfileContentType;
    }

    public File getUploadFile() {
        return uploadFile;
    }

    public void setUploadFile(File uploadFile) {
        this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
    }
    RegisterDAO dao = new RegisterDAO();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * @throws
     * Exception
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        System.out.println("filepath" + filePath);
        System.out.println("file" + getUploadFile());
        System.out.println("filename" + getUploadfileFileName());
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.uploadfileFileName);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.uploadFile, fileToCreate);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
        }
        return SUCCESS;


//        Model m = new Model();
//        String result = m.fileimport(uploadFile, uploadfileFileName);
//        String result = m.fileimport();
//        if (result.equals(SUCCESS)) {
//            return SUCCESS;
//        } else {
//            addActionError(getText(result));
//            return "failure";
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("inside validate of LA");
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [in uploading file null pointer exception near filePath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634677/in-uploading-file-null-pointer-exception-near-filepath)

Comment: Duplicate, and already answered. You haven't corrected the variable names. At least READ THE ANSWERS we give to you.......

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying to `getResourceAsStream` from the servlet context instead of using file paths.  That'll work with a WAR file.

The other issue you need to consider is that it's highly unlikely that the file will even reside on the server except for your test cases.  For remote users the file path is meaningless.  "Upload a file" will happen on a machine that's not the server.  Your code isn't correct for that case.

Comment: Nope, you can't.  Just the InputStream.  Your requirements are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

if you have deployed your application as a WAR following code will return null

```
String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private File uploadFile;
    private String uploadfileFileName;
    private String uploadfileContentType;
```

This is wrong, notice the small `f` in other properties, it should have been `F`, since the File field name is `uploadFile`

This is valid :

```
private File upload;
    private String uploadFileName;
    private String uploadContentType;
```

This one is also valid :

```
private File uploadFile;
    private String uploadFileFileName;
    private String uploadFileContentType;
```