# When I try to upload and save an image file using Struts in eclipse it shows the file name as null

Tags: java, eclipse, file-upload, struts2

This is my index page:

```xml
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="SContent-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <s:form action="clickupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <s:file name="myFile"></s:file>
 <s:submit value="Upload"/>
 </s:form> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

struts.xml

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
 <struts>
   <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
   <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="uploadSnew" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
     <action name="clickupload" class="tryupload.UploadNewFile" method="execute">
         <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">2048000</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param >
            </interceptor-ref>
             <result name="success" >/success.jsp</result>
             <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
             <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
     </action>
   </package>
 </struts>
```

When I upload a file and submit it shows:

```
     Struts Problem Report
     Struts has detected an unhandled exception: 

     Messages:  
     File: java/io/File.java 
     Line number: 291 


     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Stacktraces

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException 
         java.io.File.<init>(File.java:291)
         tryupload.UploadNewFile.execute(UploadNewFile.java:32)
         sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
         sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870)
         ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
         ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
         ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369)
         ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
         ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
         ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
         ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
         ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:309)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:340)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:307)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:423)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:250)
         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:326)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
         org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
         org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
         org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
         org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
         org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
         org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
         org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
         org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
         java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)




     You are seeing this page because development mode is enabled. Development mode, or devMode, enables extra debugging behaviors and reports to assist developers. To disable this mode, set: 

     struts.devMode=false

     in your WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties file. 
      My console:

     Sep 30, 2015 10:16:29 PM org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor warn
     WARNING: Content-Type not allowed: myFile "FiveFingerDeathPunch.jpg" "upload_1a24317f_cf06_45b2_be8d_1b56d56eab1e_00000000.tmp" image/pjpeg
     Server path:E:\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\tryupload\
     Filename:null
```

`UploadNewFile` - My action class:

```
package tryupload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;  


public class UploadNewFile extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
    /**
     * 
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest; 
    private File myFile;
    private String myFileContentType;
    private String myFileFileName;

    public File getMyFile() {
        return myFile;
        }
    public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
        this.myFile = myFile;
        }
    public String getMyFileFileName() {
        return myFileFileName;
        }
        public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
        this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;

        }
    public String getMyFileContentType() {
        return myFileContentType;
        }
    public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
        this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
        }


    public String execute() throws Exception {

        /*File saveFilePath = new File("WebContent/images" +myFileFileName);
        System.out.println("Filename:"+myFileFileName);
*/
    try {
            String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");  
          System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);  
        System.out.println("Filename:"+myFileFileName);

          File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.myFileFileName);  
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.myFile, fileToCreate);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't save file: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.getStackTrace();
            addActionError(ex.getMessage());  

            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;  

    }

}
```

Comment: that because i have created class called uploadActionBean to set and get the set the file. and i created an obj of that class in the uploadNewFile class

Comment: no its wrong. `myFile` is in current action. `FileUtils.copyFile(this.myFile, fileToCreate);`

Comment: but it still shows filename as shows null :(

Comment: first format ur code.

Comment: @satya sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Andrea Ligios it does work. thank u. thnks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the multipart request correctly, the FileUpload Interceptor must run *before* other interceptors that otherwise would mess things up. Then changing the order from

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="maximumSize">2048000</param>
    <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param >
</interceptor-ref>
```

to

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="maximumSize">2048000</param>
    <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param >
</interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
```

is enough to make it work. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29211248/1654265).

Comment: It was a hell of a long testing, wasn't it @Rohz ? :D

Comment: Not a problem at all, "bro" :D I was just kiddin