# Upload a file in a separate thread in a java webapp

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, struts2, upload

I need to make a form where users can upload big files (>200Mo). I wanted to launch the uploads in separate threads so users can launch 3-4 uploads and then do something else. My problem is the generated .tmp file is deleted when i run the secondary thread. 
I use Struts2.

What struts2 gives me:

```
private String uploadContentType;
private String uploadFileName;
private File upload;
```

I transfer those information to my thread using its constructor

```
MyThread thread=new MyThread (sourceName, uploadFileName, upload, user, database);
thread.start();
```

In the run() method:

```
System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);
System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName);

File destFile  =new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, myFileFileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);
```

And the error:

```
Src Filename:
C:\***myeclipsepath***\upload_1949ed75_1002_4ccf_b198_
25faff66563a_00000003.tmp
Dst File name: books.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException:    
C:\***myeclipsepath***\upload_1949ed75_1002_4ccf_b198_
25faff66563a_00000003.tmp  (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1068)
   at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1021)
   at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:968)
   at bo.threads.MyThread .run(MyThread .java:68)
```

When i debug step-by-step i see that the .tmp file disappear when i call thread.start().

So how can i upload files on other threads than the main one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running multiple threads in a WebApp is basically never required and almost always a bad idea.

You are probably not aware that you can [upload multiple files concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265). You can also tweak your configuration settings to allow files with a size higher than the default threshold (both per-file and per-request).

The only thing remaining to accomplish your requirement of letting the user do something else after they started uploading can be achieved by either:

1. opening the upload page in a new tab, then run a standard submit (user then change previous tab manually)
2. open the upload action in a new tab with `target="_blank"` (user then change previous tab manually)
3. upload through AJAX (but with huge size you might encounter limits and problems).

I'd go with solution n.2.

---

**EDIT**

> Thank you for your advice, it should work but **how can I close automatically the tab in my action ?**

There are many ways, for example you can return a JSP consisting of the following content:

```jsp
<script>
    window.close();
</script>
```

But consider informing the user of the positive (or negative) outcome of the operation with a more descriptive, non-self-closing page, or (if you close the tab) with a listener of some kind from the *other* tab (that would be perfect, and that would be a completely new question, so try making this work before).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it should work but how can i close automatically close the tab in my action ?

Comment: Ok i'll go with an alert for both sucess and fail and a timed closing script if the operation is successful

Comment: Good, sounds a (lot) better idea than the original one ;)