# How to Create multi processing on JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am new in JSP, When i call UploadObject.jsp, until web page is not fully loaded the page is not visible to view, so if i want to upload more than 5-10 MB of file, it's takes more than 2-3 minutes to view, so is it possible to create multi process just like Threading ?

Comment: are you asking about upload taking too much time ? or web page loading takes too much time ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782910/upload-a-file-in-a-separate-thread-in-a-java-webapp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe study these languages/technologies : JavaScript, AJAX, PHP/Servlet.

Upload example : http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

Download example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZGO13Sx_c8