# JSP doesn't allow select multiple file to upload

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I'm new to Struts2. I have written a JSP page to accept multiple file in single upload option but it doesn't accept multiple file in index page it self.

Please find below the index.jsp file.

```
<s:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="myFile">Upload your file</label>
 <s:file name="myFile" multiple="multiple" />
  <s:submit value="Upload files" />
  </s:form>
```

Please help me out from this problem. it allows single file to select.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265

Comment: Why do you say it allows single file to be selected ? Have you tried pressing the CTRL button while doing the multiple selection ?

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't allow me to select multiple file...

Comment: You need an HTML5 compliant browser. Are you on old Internet Explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

From here: [Need to upload multiple files at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1700321)

> JSP
>
> ```
> <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>  <head>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
>     <title>Multiple File Upload Example</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <s:form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
>         <s:file name="files" multiple="multiple" />
>         <s:submit value="Upload files" />
>     </s:form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> ACTION
>
> public class Upload extends ActionSupport{
>
> ```
> private List<File> files;
> private List<String> filesContentType;
> private List<String> filesFileName;
>
> /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */           
>
> public String execute() throws Exception{
>     System.out.print("\n\n---------------------------------------");
>     int i=0;
>     for (File file : files){
>         System.out.print("\nFile ["+i+"] ");
>         System.out.print("; name:"         + filesFileName.get(i));
>         System.out.print("; contentType: " + filesContentType.get(i));
>         System.out.print("; length: "      + file.length());
>         i++;
>     }
>     System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------\n");
>     return SUCCESS;
> }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Struts.xml - Max multipart size:
>
> ```
> <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="20000000" />
> ```
>
> Interceptor
>
> ```
> <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
>   <param name="maximumSize">10485760</param>
> </interceptor-ref>
> ```

Comment: Usually you should [credit the original author](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265) when copying part of the code; not sure what you should do here since you've copied the whole answer. At least go there and upvote the original one.