# Struts2 Fileupload giving null file in the action class

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2, interceptorstack

I am trying to implement the file upload process in my web application using struts2 fileUpload interceptor. below is my code in

index.jsp

```xml
<tags:form action="fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <tags:file name="fileUpload" label="Choose File"/>
   <tags:submit value="Upload"/>     
</tags:form>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<action name="fileUpload" class="com.hibernate.action.FileUploadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUploadStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">1024000</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">application/pdf</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">/viewChapters.jsp</result>
</action>
```

FileUploadAction.java

```java
public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport
{
private File fileUpload;
private String contentType;
private String fileName;
private String destPath;
/// setter and getter methods
 public String execute()
{
    destPath="C:\\WebPortal_testing";
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Source File Name:"+fileUpload);
        System.out.println("Destination File Name:"+fileName);

        File destFile= new File(destPath,fileName);
        FileUtils.copyFile(fileUpload, destFile);
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
 }
```

when I select a pdf file in the index.jsp page and click on upload button it is giving null value to the fileUpload field of the action class.

I am executing the application in debug mode and gave this

```
System.out.println("Source File Name:"+fileUpload);
```

to check what it is returning and I am getting null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Interceptor configuration is wrong**

[FileUploadStack](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-defaultxml.html) is:

```xml
<!-- Sample file upload stack -->
<interceptor-stack name="fileUploadStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

then what you're really defining is:

```xml
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">1024000</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">application/pdf</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
```

Using

- two times the fileUpload interceptor
- applying your limitations on maximumSize and allowedTypes only to the second.

Just do

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="fileUploadStack">
    <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">1024000</param>
    <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">application/pdf</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

---

**2. File attributes are wrong**

Content type and file name attributes must start with the File attribute name.

In your case:

```java
private File fileUpload;
private String fileUploadContentType;
private String fileUploadFileName;
```

You can find a full example on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265).

---

**3. You are printing the File instead of the filename**

```java
System.out.println("Source File Name:"+fileUpload);
```

That is the file, not the filename, and btw the filename is passed in the other variable.

---

Fix this and retry. Also note that is not safe to use `<tags:` as prefix when the whole world is using `<s:`. There's no gain in doing that, only complications. Just use `<s:`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
 
regarding your 

3. You are printing the File instead of the filename

I am using this only for testing purpose. I have updated every thing as per your suggestions but no luck. I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Then check carefully the setters, or post more details because everything now seems fine

Comment: sorry for the delay. I am still facing the issue. I have put that part of implementation on hold and working on other parts of the application where I am facing few other issues. I will post those doubts in a while please comment on them when free. my sincere thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question by applying the latest code tried (the one with the modifies suggested in the answer) ? So I can check what is going south

Comment: @AndreaLigios The `struts2` `fileupload` interceptor is not checking content type whether the file content is image or not. While uploading text file as image (I changed extension of file from `txt` to `png`) its accepting means file upload has been done. I think its just checking extension.  I also set `allowedTypes` as `image/bmp,image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg`. Correct me if I did wrong. I'm using `struts2.3.32` version. If I upload actual image its uploading, so its correct.

Comment: @Satya it's a browser fault. The browser detects the contentType to pass mainly basing on the extension; hence it will often send a wrong contentType if the extension is not correct. You can check it by examining the contentType in the request sent. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42803060/1654265