# Upload multiple files with a single tag <s:file>

Tags: struts2

I have a form with an option to attach a file. I would like to get multiple files using a single tag `<s:file>`.

Every time a file is appended, the option appeared to attach another file and the list of attachments below.

Comment: Refer to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/8323111/1541001 hope it helps